# Installing standalone OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I have groovy installed on my ubuntu 12.04. If i install standalone opencv without uninstalling opencv which is installed with groovy, would it be any problem?

Kindest regards
Hossain

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/97911/installing-standalone-opencv?/) by [cognitiveRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/6861/cognitiverobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2013-11-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[In this thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/128691/standalone-opencv/) someone is having a trouble in using standlone library in non-ROS situation on Groovy (and it's not yet resolved on this forum).

I might be wrong (I'm in the middle of investigating how ROS installs `OpenCV`), but installing standalone version may not become an issue if you use OpenCV separately in ROS and non-ROS? As far as I've seen none of Groovy core packages that are related to OpenCV seem to depend on the standalone cv libraries.

```
$ apt-cache depends ros-groovy-opencv2
ros-groovy-opencv2
 |Depends: libavcodec53
  Depends: libavcodec-extra-53
 |Depends: libavformat53
  Depends: libavformat-extra-53
 |Depends: libavutil51
  Depends: libavutil-extra-51
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libgcc1
  Depends: libglib2.0-0
  Depends: libgtk2.0-0
  Depends: libjasper1
  Depends: libjpeg8
  Depends: libpng12-0
  Depends: libpython2.7
  Depends: libstdc++6
 |Depends: libswscale2
  Depends: libswscale-extra-2
  Depends: libtiff4
  Depends: libv4l-0
  Depends: zlib1g
  Depends: ffmpeg
  Depends: libavcodec-dev
  Depends: libavformat-dev
  Depends: libavutil-dev
  Depends: libgtk2.0-dev
  Depends: libjasper-dev
  Depends: libjpeg-dev
    libjpeg-turbo8-dev
  Depends: libpng12-dev
  Depends: libswscale-dev
  Depends: libtiff4-dev
  Depends: libv4l-dev
  Depends: python-dev
  Depends: python-numpy
  Depends: python-support
  Depends: ros-groovy-catkin
  Depends: zlib1g-dev
  Conflicts: ros-groovy-opencv2:i386
$ dpkg -p ros-groovy-opencv2|grep Ver
Version: 2.4.6-1precise-20140305-1022-+0000
  Conflicts: ros-groovy-cv-bridge:i386
$ apt-cache depends ros-groovy-cv-bridge 
ros-groovy-cv-bridge
  Depends: libboost-python1.46.1
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libgcc1
  Depends: libpython2.7
  Depends: libstdc++6
  Depends: ros-groovy-opencv2
  Depends: libboost-all-dev
  Depends: ros-groovy-rosconsole
  Depends: ros-groovy-sensor-msgs
  Conflicts: ros-groovy-cv-bridge:i386
$ apt-cache depends ros-groovy-vision-opencv 
ros-groovy-vision-opencv
  Depends: ros-groovy-cv-bridge
  Depends: ros-groovy-image-geometry
  Conflicts: ros-groovy-vision-opencv:i386
```

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2014-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0